# Prestashop 1.7 - override homeslider module controller (hookdisplayHeader javascript)

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop-1.7

I have just discovered the new version of presashop (1.7.0).

I would like to use another javascript than the one proposed by default by the homeslider module.

```
class Ps_ImageSlider extends Module implements WidgetInterface
{
    public function hookdisplayHeader($params)
    {
        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet('modules-homeslider', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/css/homeslider.css', ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 150]);
        $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('modules-responsiveslides', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/js/responsiveslides.min.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]);
        $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('modules-homeslider', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/js/homeslider.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]);
    }
}
```

However, i can't overload it in my theme !

Do you have a procedure to suggest to me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post some of your code as its easier to help you.  Try to post only the code relevant to the problem you are having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's me again !

Therefore to the root of Prestashop, there exists a file that is called: "./override/modules". We just have to add a folder "ps_imageslider" and a file "ps_imageslider.php" and then enter the following code :

```
<?php
class Ps_ImageSliderOverride extends Ps_ImageSlider{
   public function hookdisplayHeader($params)
   {
       $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet('modules-homeslider', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/css/homeslider.css', ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 150]);
       $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('modules-YOUR_JS', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/js/YOUR_JS.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]);
       $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('modules-homeslider', 'modules/'.$this->name.'/js/homeslider.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]);
   }
}
```

Finally, you have to empty the cache.

Sorry for my English (I'm french xD).

See you soon!